# Sort list of 3 elements by particular element, then display

Tags: scheme

In my program the user will enter 3 elements for each student:

```
ID
Name
Grade
```

These are put into a list which will look like (a scheme list)

```
( (001 "Bob" 80) (002 "Sam" 85) (003 "Aaron" 94) etc . . .)
```

If the user chooses to sort by name, I'd then like the list to display the info like:

```
No.1: ID=003, Name=’’Aaron’’, Grade=94
No.2: ID=001, Name=’’Bob’’, Grade=80
No.3: ID=002, Name=’’Sam’’, Grade=85
```

I finished the function to generate the list but i'm struggling with sorting the list and displaying. any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Are you 'struggling' because you can't implement a `sort` procedure or you can't figure out the sort predicate or you can't display (something)?

Comment: @GoZoner, Oscar Lopez helped me with sorting so i'm good on that, but now i'm struggling with his implementation of display. he uses a record to display, but i get unbound variable errors when i try to do it his way. i'm trying to define the record before using the record in a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your interpreter's documentation for a [sorting procedure](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._sort%29%29). For example in Racket you can sort the following list:

```
(define lst '((001 "Bob" 80) (002 "Sam" 85) (003 "Aaron" 94)))
```

Ascending, using the name:

```
(sort lst #:key second string<?)
=> '((3 "Aaron" 94) (1 "Bob" 80) (2 "Sam" 85))
```

Descending, using the grade:

```
(sort lst #:key third >)
=> '((3 "Aaron" 94) (2 "Sam" 85) (1 "Bob" 80))
```

… You get the idea. For the second part of the question, once again refer to your interpreter's documentation. In Racket [`printf`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Writing.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._fprintf%29%29) comes in handy - for instance, for printing the records after sorting them by name:

```
(for ([i (in-naturals 1)]
      [record (sort lst #:key second string<?)])
  (printf "No.~a: ID=~a, Name=’’~a’’, Grade=~a~n"
          i
          (~a (first record) #:min-width 3 #:align 'right #:left-pad-string "0")
          (second record)
          (third record)))

=> No.1: ID=003, Name=’’Aaron’’, Grade=94
   No.2: ID=001, Name=’’Bob’’, Grade=80
   No.3: ID=002, Name=’’Sam’’, Grade=85
```

Comment: thanks. i've almost got it working, but my version of scheme (9.0.1) gives me an "unbound variable" error for record (2nd line). i tried to define it before using it but i've been struggling to get it to work for 2 hours now. any ideas?

Comment: actually i don't think printf is available on my version of scheme at all. GOSH!!

Comment: @GeorgeCostanza if you aren't using Racket (and I don't know which interpreter you're using, 0.9 is just the version number) then `for` as used above won't be available. You'll have to implement looping using the syntax in your system, at the very least `do` and `for-each` should be there. And if `printf` isn't there then you'll have to do a bit of fiddling with string procedures, but it's possible to write an equivalent answer. First step: find out which interpreter you have installed. Second step: browse through the documentation, to discover the procedures at your disposal

Answer (score 2):

An implementation of sort in Scheme is found in [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Sorting/Merge_sort#Scheme). It is called `mergesort`. At its core, it assumes that you can use `<` to compare two elements of the list for sorting purposes.

You can modify `mergesort` to take an additional argument, `less-proc`, and use it wherever `<` is used.

Then you can call `mergesort` with:

```
(mergesort lst (lambda (a b) (string<? (cadr a) (cadr b))))
```